How to Maintain Scroll Position in TableVirtuoso When State Changes?
I have a MessagesTable component that uses TableVirtuoso from react-virtuoso to render a table. When the highlightedIndex or any other state changes, the TableContainer within VirtuosoTableComponents scrolls to the top of the table, resetting the scroll position. I want to maintain the scroll position or prevent it from resetting when any state changes.
Here's a video demonstrating the issue: Video Link
I've attempted to set the scroll position manually using a useEffect hook that triggers when highlightedIndex changes. However, this approach resets the scroll position to the top of the table whenever the state changes. I'm looking for a solution that either maintains the scroll position when state changes or prevents the scroll position from resetting altogether.

use your state to refresh the firstItemIndex props in Virtuoso-react components, like
<Virtuoso
    ref={virtuoso}
    initialTopMostItemIndex={internalMessages.length - 1}
    firstItemIndex={Math.max(0, firstItemIndex)} //  here
    data={internalMessages}
    startReached={startReached}
    itemContent={(index, item) => { /* your list */ }}
/>

If you want more information, you can see this:
Reverse unlimited list sample
